# Сумма в матрице (движение по матрице вниз и вправо)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется задача. Нужно найти максимальную сумму в матрице двигаясь только вниз или вправо. Нужно решение с объяснением. Я сижу над этой задачкой уже несколько дней. Пытался решить с помощью графов, но у меня ничего не выходит. Выглядит очень просто, но у меня не хватает знаний. Прошу написать решение с объяснением.

```
Константы:
0 < n <= 100
```

Вот ссылка с кодом , что я имею : https://yadi.sk/d/VXZMw1l_PwHYow

```
Пример входа:

3                 # n Количество строк и столбцов в матрице
10 15 9           # Три строки ввода
12 3 6
20 1 17

Выход: 60
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так вы приведите свои попытки решения.

Comment: там 300 строчек проб всяких разных , я не знаю как мне сюда это загрузить, могу текстовый файл на яндекс диск загрузить и вставить сюда.

Comment: Кинул ссылочку на яндекс

Comment: Рекурсивный поиск в глубину и готово, что именно не понятно?

Comment: Если бы мне было понятно как это делать я бы не задавал вопрос, я захожу на стак оферфлоу задать, если прям вообще в тупике нахожусь, как сейчас.

Comment: Это задача на динамическое программирование. Пусть `max_sum(i, j)` функция которая решает задачу если мы начинаем с клетки `i, j`. В качестве ответа нужно вычислить `max_sum(0, 0)`. `max_sum(n - 1, n - 1)` вычислить не сложно. `max_sum(i, j) = a[i][j] + max(max_sum(i + 1, j), max_sum(i, j + 1))`. Это почти всё что нужно чтобы написать функцию `max_sum`.

Comment: Ну эти подсказки мало чем мне помогли.

Comment: Может вы подумали , что мне просто нужно посчитать сумму идя вниз, а дойдя до последнего элемента снизу , повернуть направо. Тут можно изначально двигаться вправо, вниз и поворачивать тоже вправо и вниз.

Comment: дополните вопрос, как надо идти ? 10+1+12+17+20 ?

Comment: Поменял ссылку, теперь можно не скачивать , а читать прямо с браузера.

Comment: @Интик там же написано как надо идти. Можно вниз и вправо, главное чтобы начало было в левом верхнем углу, конец в правом нижнем углу и посчитать где получилось больше.

Comment: @Michaelan, я ничего не думал про направления. Не думал про программирование. Я думал про функцию max_sum, которая возвращает самую большую сумму если мы начали из определённой клетки. Я думал как значение этой функции связано с её значениями в соседних клетках.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я видимо неправильно воспользовался вашей функцией, потому что у меня выдаёт ответ 19729 0_0. Я не понимаю , что мне делать , я не изучал динамическое программирование, но пытался, в итоге у меня все задачи либо не выходят, либо выходят , но в них сложность большая.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-path-in-a-matrix-from-top-left-to-bottom-right/?ref=rp

Comment: @strawdog Спасибо, вроде первое задание решило так как надо, как раз с хоть каким-то обьяснением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def f(arr, n):
    res = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
    res[0][0] = arr[0][0]
    for i in range(1, n):
        res[i][0] = res[i - 1][0] + arr[i][0]
        res[0][i] = res[0][i - 1] + arr[0][i]
    
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(n - i):
            res[i][i + j] = max(res[i - 1][i + j], res[i][i + j - 1]) + arr[i][i + j]
            res[i + j][i] = max(res[i + j][i - 1], res[i + j - 1][i]) + arr[i + j][i]

    return res[n - 1][n - 1]

arr = [[10, 15, 9],
           [12, 3,  6],
           [20, 1, 17]]

print(f(arr, 3))
```

`res` в начале:

> ```
> 0 0 0
> 0 0 0
> 0 0 0
> ```

присваиваем первому элементу значение:

> ```
> 10 0 0
> 0  0 0
> 0  0 0
> ```

заполняем левую и верхнию грань, для левой бирем значение из `arr` и складывает с элементом который выше него в `res`, тоже самое и для верхней но бирем элемент слева:

> ```
> 10 25 34
> 22 0  0
> 42 0  0
> ```

постепенно заполняем остальное, беря при этом максимально большого соседа

> ```
> 10 25 34
> 22 28 40
> 42 43 60
> ```

---

Либо так с помощью рекурсии

```
def f(arr, n, i = 0, j = 0):
    sum_ = arr[i][j]
    
    if i + 1 < n and j + 1 < n:
        sum_ += max(
            f(arr, n, i + 1, j),
            f(arr, n, i, j + 1)
        )
    elif i + 1 < n:
        sum_ += f(arr, n, i + 1, j)
    elif j + 1 < n:
        sum_ += f(arr, n, i, j + 1)
    
    return sum_
    
arr =  [[10, 15, 9],
           [12, 3,  6],
           [20, 1, 17]]
print(f(arr, 3))
```

Comment: А можете пожалуйста расписать в коментариях , что и как , мне очень нужно разобраться в этом. Мой вариант проходит, а загружать ваш код не хочу, хочу сам написать.

Answer (score 3):

Существует термин "Динамическое программирование". Он связан как раз с подобными задачами, и конкретно эта является базовой задачей по теме.

Суть динамического программирования заключается в получении ответа для большого случая через решение меньших и их объединение. Например, простейшей задачей на ДП является "Кузнечик": "Кузнечик может прыгать на одну или две травинки за один раз. Сколькими различными путями он может прийти на N-ную травинку?". Для этой задачи формула ДП осень проста: `dp[n] = dp[n - 1] + dp[n - 2]`. Очень простая закономерность, которую можно вычислить за `O(n)`, не перебирая все возможные пути за `O(2^n)` (на всякий случай скажу, что конкретная эта задача решается за `O(logN)`, но если вам это интересно, то прочитайте в интернете сами).

В вашем случае, попробуйте считать максимальную сумму для каждой клетки, а не пытайтесь сразу прийти к ответу для конечной. Тогда для каждой конкретной ячейки вы заметите, что в нее всегда выгоднее приходить из той, в которой накопленная сумма уже больше. Данное утверждение, конечно, требует доказательств, но в данном случае у вас есть весь интернет, собственная голова и клише доказательств от противного.

В итоге, мы имеем правило `dp[x][y] = max(dp[x - 1][y] + dp[x][y - 1]) + a[x][y]`, согласно которому можно заполнить все ячейки, кроме первой строки и первого столбца. К ячейкам из первого столбца и первой строки существует ровно один путь, так что и посчитать там заранее максимальное значение можно очевидным образом.

Comment: `эта задача решается за O(logN)` - это про кузнечика? Есть же формула Бине для фибоначчи, O(1).

Comment: Формула Бине на компьютере вычисляет числа Фибоначчи приблизительно. Есть точный алгоритм, который использует неограниченные целые и вычисляет n-ное число Фибоначчи за логарифм от n. Хотя тут есть небольшое лукавство, это алгоритм работает все же медленнее логарифма.